# AlarmManger setRepeating stop functioning

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-broadcastreceiver

I wanting to fire a notification every hour.

I using the setRepeating in the AlarmManager service, the problem is when I am closing my app the manager not broadcast to my BroadcastReceiver.

My BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "notify_001")
                .setContentTitle("URL Database")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                .setContentText("You didn't use the URLDatabase app for a while.\nYour urls feel lonely.")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("notify_001",
                    "URLDatabaseNotification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        manager.notify(0, notification);
        Log.i("URLDatabase", "Received");
    }
}
```

My code for the AlarmManager (I using this in the onCreate of my activity):

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*60, pendingIntent);
```

Am I need to create custom service that will work in the background?

Comment: First of all read about background restrictions on API >23 and 26. Answer for your question is - depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I wrote in the post what I want to do "I wanting to fire a notification every hour.".

Comment: I saw. What should happen every hour ? You want to grab some data from server? You want to get user location or what ? This is important, because you maybe try to do smth in wrong way. On latest API versions, there is no guarantee that your alarm will fire in exact time, except you setup alarm as real clock alarm(and you will see small icon in status bar) using method setAlarmClock().

Comment: I just want to notify every 1 hour that the user didn't used the app for 1 hour like as a reminder.

Comment: I found out that the AlarmManger does firing the notification only when the app is working or in the background, but when I closing the app it is stoping to alerting.

Comment: What do you mean "close the app"? Also what device are you testing on?

Comment: Closing the app means dismissing it from the running apps and I am using Oneplus 3T

Comment: I did read that android deleting unnecessary services to save battery life, maybe this is the problem.

Comment: On some devices you need to manually add your app to a list of "protected apps" or "apps that are allowed to run in the background". If your app is not in this list, Android will not automatically restart it or call any `BroadcastReceiver`s in it. Please check if your device has this (look in the power, battery or security settings)

Comment: Is there a way throw the code to allow my app to do so alone and not requesting it from the user?

Comment: No. On these devices the user MUST manually add or enable the app in the settings. All you can do is suggest to the user that he must do this. Sorry.

Comment: Did you check your device? Does it have this list of "protected apps"? If you add the app to the list manually does it solve your problem? Please let us know because that will benefit other users!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
Will fire each 10 minutes.

Broadcast receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final int REQUESTED_CODE_ALARM = 101;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // interval in minutes
    long fireTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 60000;

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context, REQUESTED_CODE_ALARM, alertNewsIntent, 0);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, fireTime, alarmPendingIntent);
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, fireTime, alarmPendingIntent);
}}
```

Use this code to start alarm(and fire first time):

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
sendBroadcast(alarmIntent);
```

To stop alarm:

```
public void stopAlertAlarm(){
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent alarmReceiver = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent alertNewsPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this, AlarmReceiver.REQUESTED_CODE_ALARM, alarmReceiver, 0);

    alarmManager.cancel(alertNewsPendingIntent);
}
```

**Important:** do not forget to register receiver in your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".services.AlarmReceiver" />
```

Comment: but this code isn't repeating every 10 min. I want to fire notification every 1 hour even when the user is out of the app

Comment: I found out that the AlarmManger does firing the notification only when the app is working or in the background, but when I closing the app it is stoping to alerting.